# JMETER: How to calculate the difference between two HTTP Sampler's response(elapsed) time value

Tags: jmeter

- **I have send two HTTP requests through JMETER.**
- **Measure the individual elapsed time or response time value.**
- **Compute the difference between the two values.**

e.g.,

- HTTP Sampler - 1: Measure Time : 1000 ms
- HTTP Sampler - 2: Measure Time : 800 ms
- Calculate the difference : 1000 - 800 = 200 ms

This two samplers has to executed multiple times.

Solution which i am thinking is to use Sampler Data Writer listener, in order to write the elapsed time value in csv file.
Finally use a VBA script to calculate the difference.

Can you please let me know if there is any alternate solution for this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Beanshell Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) to calculate difference on the fly

Add a Beanshell Post Processor element as a child of HTTP Sampler 1 with the following code:

```
long request1 = prev.getTime(); // get HTTP Sampler 1 execution time
vars.put("sampler1", String.valueOf(request1)); // store execution time to "sampler1" variable
```

And do the same for HTTP Sampler 2. In this case the code should look like:

```
long request2 = prev.getTime(); // get HTTP Sampler 2 execution time
long request1 = Long.parseLong(vars.get("sampler1")); // get HTTP Sampler 1 execution time from variable
long delta = (request1 - request2); // calculate difference
log.info("Time difference is: " + delta + " ms"); // print difference to jmeter.log file
```

In jmeter.log file you should see something like

```
2014/07/16 14:00:02 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Time difference is: 200 ms
```

Similarly you can store it to a file

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("delta.csv", true);
out.write((String.valueOf(delta)).getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Or calculate average difference for all requests.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for comprehensive information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter.